# MS Access, DoEvents to exit loop

Tags: vba, ms-access, while-loop, onkeydown

What I'd like to accomplish:

```
Do While ctr < List and Break = False
   code that works here...
DoEvents
  If KeyDown = vbKeyQ
      Break = True
  End If
loop
```

Break out of a loop by holding down a key (eg, Q). I've read up on DoEvents during the loop in order to achieve the functionality that I want. The idea is to have a Do While loop run until either the end of the list is reached or when Q is held down. I'm having issues getting the code to work the way I want, so I'm reaching out to hopefully end the frustration. My experience with VBA is very limited.

UPDATE - More code to expose where the problem might be. This is all in the order I have it (in case order of subs makes a difference:

```
Private Sub Form_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
Dim strChar As String

strChar = UCase(Chr(KeyAscii))
If strChar = "Q" Then
    blnQuit = True
    Debug.Print "Q pressed"
End If
End Sub
Private Sub Master_Report_Click()
Dim i As Integer
Dim Deptarray
blnQuit= False

If IsNull(Me.Hospital) Then
    MsgBox ("Please Choose a Hospital")
Else
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Report Print/Update", acNormal, , , , acDialog
    If Report_choice = "Current_List" Then
        Debug.Print "Create master rec report"
        DoCmd.OpenReport "Master Rec Report", acViewPreview
        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdZoom100
    ElseIf Report_choice = "Update_All" Then
        total = (DCM_Dept.ListCount - 1)
            ctr = 1
            Do While ctr < (DCM_Dept.ListCount) And LoopBreak = False
                Debug.Print "LoopBreak: "; LoopBreak
                Debug.Print "Counter: "; ctr
                DCM_Dept.Value = DCM_Dept.Column(0, ctr)
                Update_Site (Me.Hospital)
                ctr = ctr + 1
                'DoEvents
                   ' If vbKeyQ = True Then
                    'LoopBreak = True
                    'End If
            Loop
            Debug.Print "Update loop exited"
        Debug.Print "Create master rec report"
        DoCmd.OpenReport "Master Rec Report", acViewPreview
        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdZoom100
    Else
    End If
End If
End Sub

Private Sub Update_Site(Site As String)

If IsNull(Me.Hospital) Then
    MsgBox ("Please Choose a Hospital")
ElseIf IsNull(Me.DCM_Dept) Then
    MsgBox ("Please Choose a Department")
ElseIf Site = "FORES" Then
    Debug.Print "Run FORES update macro"
    DoCmd.RunMacro "0 FORES Master Add/Update"
ElseIf Site = "SSIUH" Then
    Debug.Print "Run SSIUH update macro"
    DoCmd.RunMacro "0 SSIUH Master Add/Update"
End If
End Sub
```

Report_choice and LoopBreak are both Public variables. My original idea was to have a popup form floating over the main form to display a counter ("Processing department X of Y") and a button to break the loop on there. I realized that the form was unresponsive while the Update_Site() was running its macro so I decided to go with holding a key down instead.

So, where do I go from here to get OnKeyDown to work? Or, is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set the `Key Preview` of the form to Yes and add a variable `blnQuit` and a key press event in your form like this:

```
Private blnQuit As Boolean

'form
Private Sub Form_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
    Dim strChar As String

    strChar = UCase(Chr(KeyAscii))
    If strChar = "Q" Then
        blnQuit = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Then check the `blnQuit` in your `Do While` condition, like this:

```
blnQuit = False
Do While ctr < List And Not blnQuit
   code that works here...
   DoEvents
loop
```

Comment: I implemented the changes as you suggested. The key press is recognized before running the Sub. However, once in the sub it doesn't return anything and after finishing it does not work until closing the form and reopening it. Do I need to have something after 'DoEvents' in the loop?

Comment: Are you referring to the sub Update_Site (Me.Hospital)?  If this sub is on separate module, then you may need to declare the blnQuit as public and put it on a module in order to use it inside the Update_Site().

Comment: The Update_Site function is on the same form, so I assume that is within the same module? I'll update the main post with the code from that as well. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: I found the problem. I had a bit of rogue code that was messing up the KeyPress check. It works perfectly now. Thanks for your help!